# arm-none-eabi-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: arm, gdb, shared-libraries, ncurses, arm-none-eabi-gcc

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
64-bit
3.36.3 Gnome
Intel core-i7-975H
31.2GiB Memory
1.6 TB Disk Space
Had my flu vaccine
COVID-19: Neg, but I'm boring and don't go anywhere anyway...

I've tried a few fixes, including this one:

[Message "Unable to run arm-none-eabi-gdb: cannot find libncurses.so.5"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53450745/message-unable-to-run-arm-none-eabi-gdb-cannot-find-libncurses-so-5)

But no love. I still continue to receive the same error. I'm trying to flash a softdevice using Arduino IDE v1.8.13. GDB version here:

[arm-none-eabi-gdb --version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xdS2.png)

libncurses versions here:

[dpkg -l '*ncurses*' | grep '^ii'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ8Ei.png)

I do not know what else to try or check. Would someone have any thoughts on what further to check?

@MarkPlotnick - I ran ls -ld $(dpkg -S libncurses.so.5), the result:

[ls -ld $(dpkg -S libncurses.so.5)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eSDr.png)

Then I checked specifically if libncurses5:i386 was installed by trying to install it and it shows the that:

```
libncurses5:i386 is already the newest version (6.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried one more time a little differently:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libudev1:i386
```

Then libudev1:i386 was the only package to install. But if I try to find the file:

```
~$ locate libncurses5:i386
```

Then I get five file in this location:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:i386.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:i386.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:i386.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:i386.symbols
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libncurses5:i386.triggers
```

It's like Schödinger File...

Comment: Please replace the link to the images by textual output formatted in code in your question  - use the 'double brace' menu item for this.

Comment: Can you run  `ls -ld $(dpkg -S libncurses.so.5)` to see if the file exists?

Comment: @Frant - Thanks for the ProTip, but the rules are "You need at least 10 reputation to post images". So the only way I could post the images was to link them like I did. Sorry, it's a little Busch league but the best I could do.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick - I replied to you up in my post. I think you're on to something. It seems these files are there and they're not there... :/

Comment: @Carbon: my point was: do not provide images when you can provide text.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since you are running a 64 bit version of Ubuntu, you should verify you installed the Linux 64 bit version of the [Arduino IDE v1.18.13](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software). If this is not the case, this may explain why installing i386 packages did not fix your problem -  If you did not, I would strongly suggest to remove the Linux 32 bit version, and install the Linux 64 bit version instead.

This verification can be done by executing the following command:

```
file ~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
```

You should see something like:

```
/home/user/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, stripped
```

The important information here would be `ELF 64-bit LSB executable`.

The 64 bit version of `libncurses.so.5` is of course missing:

```
ldd ~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffccf1ed000)
        libncurses.so.5 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f68fa317000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f68fa125000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f68fa11f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f68fa482000)
```

It can be installed using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
```

After running `sudo ldconfig`:

```
ldd  ~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc41f5000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f890c00d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f890bebe000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f890bccc000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f890bcc6000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f890bc98000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f890c04f000)
```

Your `GDB` should now be functional:

```
~/.arduino15/packages/arduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb -tui
```

[image: Arduino-provided arm-none-eabi-gdb]

Note that the same kind of issues may happen with the [GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm/downloads) as well on Ubuntu 20.04.1. It can be fixed by installing the missing packages:

`sudo apt-get install libtinfo5 libncursesw5 libpython2.7`

Comment: It installed libncursew5 and libpython2.7, then apt update, but no fix yet.

Comment: 1) Did you run the exact command above ? libtinfo5 was needed in my brand new system.
2) Are you getting an error message ? If yes, which one ?

Comment: Hi @Carbon if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey @Frant. Thanks, but these didn't solve the issue. I'm presently reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 and starting from scratch with Arduino IDE... I'll post back so. Probably over the weekend. I must have broken a symlink or some else.

Comment: And user *Carbon* [left the building 8 days later](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients).